# Windows 8, SkyDrive and OpenPackage zip-files

Tags: .net, zip, windows-8, onedrive, open-packaging-convention

I have a structure of folders and xml-files on a regular asp.net/iis server (a file based database in xml). I modify the database over the net using WCF -> get/post xml. This works fine.

To gather all files into a more manageable unit, I used a OpenPackage zip-file. I can still modify its state using my WCF-service, file by file, without having to transfer the entire file back and forth.

Now I want to put this zip-based database on SkyDrive instead. The question is, will I be able to somehow get and post individual content-files from/to this file through SkyDrive? Or do I now have to send the entire file back and forth when modifying it's state?

Since OpenPackage is part of the .NET-framework and SkyDrive will be a integrated part of Windows 8 and Explorer, i was hoping it would be possible to open a package while still on the server and only download individual files from it, and also upload individual files to it. Does anyone know?

Even if the file had compression turned on and the entire zip would have to be unpacked first, this could in theory be done on the SkyDrive server before returning the requested file. I hope Microsoft sees the use of this and adds it to the SkyDrive API, if they haven't already.

A work around would be to not use zip-files and store all individual files unpacked on SkyDrive. But this would not be very manageble by the user I think.